# No IRC demand: city won't grow and citizens leave the city

Tags: cities-skylines

Two days ago I started a new city. I'm an experienced user, so I know how to deal with most of the problems, but not this one.

At some point, IRC demand dropped and only bounces between -2 and 2 continuously. 
Everything is fine; education, healthcare, and any other service. Even traffic is at 96%, so everything is fine.

I've checked the industrial zone and every factory has a few over-educated workers, what seems to be a part of the issue. For a short term of time, industrial demand scaled up to 30, so I managed to put more industrial zone, but it went wrong, "no workers!". Factories started abandoning after this.

I've tried removing all commercial zones, but when I do, commercial demand increases until I put commercial zone. Then, it drops back again at 0. Citizens are leaving my city. I dropped from 2500 to 1900. After all this I thought that building a university is a great deal, but I still can't build one.

Seems that I can't do nothing without cheats, and I don't want that (or at least if there's no more options). If anyone here has the solution for this, I'll be very grateful. Every city I've started ended like this.

*(Using traffic and green cities DLCs. May I install Industries? Complex manufacturing plants will demand citizens with higher education, that may solve the problem, right?)*

Comment: How's the education levels in your city? I think I had a similar issue once where my population was too educated and nobody wanted to field the low paying jobs and it created a chain reaction since the higher end jobs couldn't get supplies from the low end jobs.

Comment: @Xander about ~12-15% of the population has no education. I tried lowering down education expenses to see if it produced any results, but nothing happens. Still thinking that buying Industries DLC might be a solution, but that's not the first option.

Comment: I have all DLC and still had this issue. You shouldn't need a DLC to play the game. I'd just wait it out and just not build any more education buildings for a while.

Comment: @Xander okay. What if I delete some schools? Would it work?

Comment: How much population and education buildings do you have?

Comment: @Xander right now I have 3900 population and 2 schools, 1 community school and 2 highschools.

Comment: Hmm, IRC is an actual term so searching for this gives me nothing useful... what does IRC mean in Cities Skylines?

Comment: @Nelson It's the green, blue and orange bars in the HUD which represent the demand for more Residential, Commercial and Industrial areas. The name "IRC" for such a widget in a city builder comes all the way back from the first Sim City which introduced such a widget and labeled the three bars with "I", "R" and "C". Although in the context of Cities Skylines RCI would be more correct due to the order of the bars, the term IRC is very ingrained in the city builder gamer community.

Answer (score 2):

This is because your city is clogged with old people, let me explain, when the children grow up to young adults they get tired of living in the houses with those old people who were young when you started this new game, so the present young adults leave the city while the old people live in the city alone, making new residential areas would make your resident move from house to house, thus solving your problem(plus your population would increase behind your back, make sure that your services are strong enough to handle the population increase).